# Identify unique values within pandas dataframe rows that share a common id number

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, duplicates

Here is a sample df:

```
data = {"Brand":{"0":"BrandA","1":"BrandA","2":"BrandB","3":"BrandB","4":"BrandC","5":"BrandC"},"Cost":{"0":18.5,"1":19.5,"2":6,"3":6,"4":17.69,"5":18.19},"IN STOCK":{"0":10,"1":15,"2":5,"3":1,"4":12,"5":12},"Inventory Number":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":2,"3":2,"4":3,"5":3},"Labels":{"0":"Black","1":"Black","2":"White","3":"White","4":"Blue","5":"Blue"},"Maximum Price":{"0":30.0,"1":35.0,"2":50,"3":45.12,"4":76.78,"5":76.78},"Minimum Price":{"0":23.96,"1":25.96,"2":12.12,"3":17.54,"4":33.12,"5":28.29},"Product Name":{"0":"Product A","1":"Product A","2":"ProductB","3":"ProductB","4":"ProductC","5":"ProductC"}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

My actual data set is much larger, but maintains the same pattern of there being 2 rows that share the same Inventory Number throughout.

My goal is to create a new data frame that contains only the inventory numbers where a cell value is not duplicated across both rows, and for those inventory numbers, only contains the data from the row with the lower index that is different from the other row.

For this example the resulting data frame would need to look like:

```
data = {"Inventory Number":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3},"Cost":{"0":18.50,"1":"","2":17.69},"IN STOCK":{"0":10,"1":5,"2":""},"Maximum Price":{"0":30,"1":50,"2":""},"Minimum Price":{"0":23.96,"1":12.12,"2":33.12}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

The next time this would run, perhaps nothing changed in the "Maximum Price", so that column would need to not be included at all.

I was hoping someone would have a clean solution using groupby, but if not, i imagine the solution would include dropping all duplicates. then looping through all of the remaining inventory numbers, evaluating each column for duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
icol = 'Inventory Number'
d0 = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
i = d0.groupby(icol).cumcount()

d1 = d0.set_index([icol, i]).unstack(icol).T

d1[1][d1[1] != d1[0]].unstack(0)

                   Cost IN STOCK Maximum Price Minimum Price
Inventory Number                                            
1                  19.5       15            35         25.96
2                  None        1         45.12         17.54
3                 18.19     None          None         28.29
```

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear. I need something to evaluate where data has effectively changed, as the way the file is generated is appending an old file to a new file. I want a final file that is as small as possible with only values where data has changed.

Comment: @YaleNewman Have you tried this code?  I think it does what you described.

Comment: My concern is that with hard coding a list of column names, it is leaving out the possibility of the columns that are not included to not be evaluated. Also, will this drop an entire column if there are no unique values in that column? I can easily change cols to equal all possible columns, so if this code meets the 2nd criteria, it will do what i need. I'll play around with it on my end. Thanks:)

Comment: @YaleNewman are you saying you want only the cells that have changed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [68]: cols = ['Cost','IN STOCK','Inventory Number','Maximum Price','Minimum Price']

In [69]: df[cols].drop_duplicates(subset=['Inventory Number'])
Out[69]:
   Cost  IN STOCK Inventory Number  Maximum Price  Minimum Price
0  18.5        10           100566           30.0          23.96
```

Comment: I should have been more specific, the rows with unique data will always be changing and will not be the same for all rows. I'll add more to the sample to make it more clear.